# Java: Why splitting String gone wrong?

Tags: java, string, split

I got a String from a .csv and want to split it:

```
String line = "1,2,3,,,,false,true,,,false,false,,,,,,,,,,,,";
String data[] = line.split(",");
```

This is the result of the array:

```
data[0] - "1"
data[1] - "2"
data[2] - "3"
data[3] - ""
data[4] - ""
data[5] - ""
data[6] - "false"
data[7] - "true"
data[8] - ""
data[9] - ""
data[10] - "false"
data[11] - "false"
```

Why are the last "" lines cutted away from the array?

Comment: Instead of manually parsing a csv file, it is more safe to use an established jar for it

Comment: why is it more safe?

Comment: the jar would have already handled all the errors that may be produced. Why reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -1 parameter

```
String data[] = line.split(",", -1);
```

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

"The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.** If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded. "

When you specify no argument calling `public String[] split(String regex)` it uses default as 0.

From javadoc: "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero."

Comment: Can u explain why "-1" works for it?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

the API says
"Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."